# OpenSL audio on Android stop when I lock screen 5.0.1 OK 6.0.1 Not OK

Tags: android, audio, android-service, opensl, opus

I made an android app, that streams voice from local wifi network. To listen and stream I use Opus C API in JNI to decode, and OpenSL Audio to read.

I call the JNI from Service, like that.

```
    public class StreamService extends Service {

        private NativeReceiver mNativeReceiver;
...

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Gérer la requête
        mNativeReceiver = new NativeReceiver();
        mCanPlay = mNativeReceiver.init();
            mNativeReceiver.startNativeReceiver();
    ...        
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

It's works very well, when I click on my Button, this service is called, and I get sound out from my android smartphone.

BUT, when I lock the screen of my smartphone, sound is like "muted", when I unlock sound is playing. Only on 6.0.X not on 5.0.X

So my first thinking was network packet was stopped, I made a debug and my smartphone continue to receive network packets.

My Service running, just sound is muted.

For the JNI OpenSL, I use this snippet of code:

To call my JNI:

```
public void startNativeReceiver() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                // set priority
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                 start();
           }
        }).start();
    }
```

And that call this:

```
   const int queue_elements_num = 20;
    const int start_after = 4;
    SpscCircularQueue *queue = NULL;

    OpusDecoder *opus_dec = NULL;
    uint32_t samplerate = 24000;
    float frame_length = 20;

    bool player_initialized = false;
    bool player_started = false;
    int frames_in_queue = 0;

    while (!rcv_th_terminate) {
        ssize_t rcv_len = read(udp_sock, rcv_buf, sizeof(rcv_buf));
        if (rcv_len <= 0) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "SMPlayer",
                            "Failed to receive UDP data");
            continue;
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SMPlayer",
                            "reading");
        if (!player_initialized) {
            if (rcv_buf[0] != 0x01) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SMPlayer",
                                    "Unsupported version of SMPlayer "
                                    "streaming protocol");
                return NULL;
            }
            /* initialize decoder */
            int opus_err = 0;
            opus_dec = opus_decoder_create(samplerate, 1, &opus_err);
            if (!opus_dec) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SMPlayer",
                                    "unable to initialize OPUS decoder, "
                                    "error code - %d", opus_err);
                return NULL;
            }

            /* initialize circular queue */
            uint32_t frame_buf_size = samplerate / 1000 * frame_length * 2;
            queue = spsc_circular_queue_alloc(queue_elements_num, frame_buf_size);
            if (!queue) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SMPlayer",
                                    "unable to allocate SPSC Circular Queue");
                opus_decoder_destroy(opus_dec);
                return NULL;
            }

            /* initialize the play and start the playback */
            osl_player_init(queue, samplerate);
            player_initialized = true;
        } else {
            int dec_samples = opus_decode(opus_dec, rcv_buf + 2, rcv_len - 2,
                                        (int16_t *)dec_buf, sizeof(dec_buf), 0);
            if (dec_samples <= 0) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SMPlayer",
                                    "failed to decode the data");
                osl_player_terminate();
                spsc_circular_queue_free(queue);
                opus_decoder_destroy(opus_dec);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            while (!spsc_circular_queue_push(queue, dec_buf) && !rcv_th_terminate)
                usleep((useconds_t)(frame_length * 1000.0));

            if (!player_started) {
                frames_in_queue++;

                if (frames_in_queue == start_after) {
                    osl_player_jumpstart(queue);
                    player_started = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    osl_player_terminate();

    if (empty_buf_cnt)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SMPlayer",
                            "Empty buffers played: %" PRIu64, empty_buf_cnt);

    spsc_circular_queue_free(queue);
    opus_decoder_destroy(opus_dec);
}
```

Any ideas ?! Thanks a looot !!

EDIT: On Android 5.0.1 it's works, on Android 6.0.1 it does't ?! Why ??

EDIT2: My permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
```

EDIT 3 : I don't record, I only listen

EDIT 4: After put permissions, RECORD AUDIO, no changes, on Android Marshmallow (Samsung S5) when I lock the screen, my app is like muted!

Comment: look at this to check for your permissions and add the needed ones. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: RECORD_AUDIO is a dangerous permission ... u need to add it at runtime to fix in marshmallow

Comment: I add it to try, but i don't think II need this permission, cause I don't record but only listen through wifi network, but i going to try it quickly ;)

Comment: I put permission, I have record audio, but no differences !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your permission expires in 6.0 and higher android versions, so you check your permissions if your permission is in Dangerous permission then give it dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand the permission you deal with ? In my manifest ?